# Add a strikethrough a c# string

Tags: c#

I need to add a strikethrough a c# string.

I have an old price and a new price and I want to add a strikethrough the old price.

For example: `"4̶.̶9̶9̶ 2.99"`

Answer (score -1):

Use this extension method:

```
public static string StrikeThrough(this string value)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var character in value)
        sb.Append(character + "\u0336");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You answer your own question the same time as you ask it?

Comment: This won't work in a console app.

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this depending upon how/where the string is displayed.

Comment: @Magnus [Self answers are perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: or `sb.Append(character).Append('\u0336');` - no intermediate strings